# How to get correct disparity map after stereo calibration?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera, camera-calibration

I am trying to generate disparity maps for the two image with calibrated cameras but I am not able to get any decent results, I have tried tweaking the parameters based on understanding what they do. The cameras I have calibrate are very heterogeneous,one is a thermal camera and other is normal optical camera.

Rectified images:

LEFT:
[image]

RIGHT:
[image]

Script I am using to tune the parameters:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv; cv2 = cv

imgL = cv2.imread('LEFT.png', 0)
imgR = cv2.imread('RIGHT.png', 0)

blockSize = 11
min_disparity = 50
max_disparity = 150
P1 = 8
P2 = 32

stereo = cv2.StereoSGBM_create(
    minDisparity=min_disparity,
    numDisparities=(max_disparity - min_disparity),
    blockSize=blockSize,
    P1=3*blockSize*blockSize * P1,
    P2=3*blockSize*blockSize * P2,
    disp12MaxDiff=0,
    preFilterCap=0,
    uniquenessRatio=10,
#   speckleWindowSize=100,
#   speckleRange=1,
#   mode=cv.StereoSGBM_MODE_SGBM
#   #mode=cv.StereoSGBM_MODE_HH
)

def redraw():
    disparity = stereo.compute(imgL,imgR)

    out = (disparity / np.float32(16)) / max_disparity

    #disparity = stereo.compute(imgR,imgL)

    cv.imshow("out", out)


def on_blockSize(pos):
    global blockSize
    blockSize = 1 - (1 - pos) // 2 * 2
    stereo.setBlockSize(blockSize)
    redraw()

def on_mindisparity(pos):
    global min_disparity
    min_disparity = pos
    stereo.setMinDisparity(min_disparity)
    stereo.setNumDisparities(max_disparity - min_disparity)
    redraw()

def on_maxdisparity(pos):
    global max_disparity
    max_disparity = pos
    stereo.setNumDisparities(max_disparity - min_disparity)
    redraw()

def on_P1(pos):
    global P1
    P1 = pos
    stereo.setP1(3*blockSize*blockSize * P1)
    redraw()

def on_P2(pos):
    global P2
    P2 = pos
    stereo.setP2(3*blockSize*blockSize * P2)
    redraw()

def set_disp12MaxDiff(pos):
    stereo.setDisp12MaxDiff(pos)
    redraw()

def set_preFilterCap(pos):
    stereo.setPreFilterCap(pos)
    redraw()


cv.namedWindow("out")
cv.createTrackbar("blockSize", "out", blockSize, 51, on_blockSize)
cv.createTrackbar("minDisparity", "out", min_disparity, 200, on_mindisparity)
cv.createTrackbar("maxDisparity", "out", max_disparity, 200, on_maxdisparity)
cv.createTrackbar("P1", "out", P1, 64, on_P1)
cv.createTrackbar("P2", "out", P2, 64, on_P2)
cv.createTrackbar("disp12MaxDiff", "out", 0, 100, set_disp12MaxDiff)
cv.createTrackbar("preFilterCap", "out", 0, 100, set_preFilterCap)



redraw()
while True:
    key = cv.waitKey()
    if key == -1:
        break
    print(key)
```

RESULTING DISPARITY:
[image]

What am I doing wrong here? I believe that the calibration is pretty good because the rectified images are vertically aligned. My end goal is to be able to match corresponding pixels or ROIs from the rectified optical image (right) to thermal(left).

Comment: those two pictures **can't** be used for block matching. one is visible light, the other is infrared. the scene looks entirely different.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz is there any other approach I can try out here? As mentioned in the post my end goal is to be able to match corresponding pixels or ROIs from the rectified optical image (right) to thermal(left)

Comment: If limited to human faces you could try to find facial landmark detection from infrared images. In general, maybe a gradient or edge or shape matching might work? But probably very experimental...

Comment: you need: one stereo cam (2 rgb cameras or one kinect/whatever), one thermal cam, extrinsic calibrations between all that, and the 3D point cloud. then you can map the IR picture _into_ the scene, i.e. onto the point cloud or surface representation, and then you can map that back into the RGB camera's view. you could also map the RGB picture into the scene (the point cloud should have that color info already) and then into the IR view.